# lualatex using vebatim package

Tags: luatex, verbatim

This was working and I don't see what has changed, but the code below is now throwing a "Missing \endcsname inserted" error.

If I just press Return, lualatex continues, reads the text file myfile.lua, and prints it perfectly verbatim.  Doesn't seem to matter whether the file is UTF-8 or ASCII encoded (I usually use the former).  Windows 10 machine if that matters.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{verbatim}%

\RequirePackage{luacode}%

\begin{luacode*}
function buildPath(...)                                                                                       
    -- get the system path separator                    
    local pathseparator = package.config:sub(1,1)       

    -- get the arguments                                
    local elements = {...}                              

    -- return the elements with the path separator      
    return table.concat(elements, pathseparator)        
end                                                     

-- Get the current path.             
function getPath(filename)                                                                                     
-- Print the current path. According to the documentation, if -2 is used, 
-- then the strings are read as if the result of detokenize: all characters 
-- have catcode 12 except space, which  has catcode 10.   

    tex.print(-2, buildPath(lfs.currentdir(), filename))
end       
\end{luacode*}

\DeclareRobustCommand\getPath[1]{\luadirect{getPath(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\verbatiminput{\getPath{myfile.lua}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the sense of \getPath? \verbatiminput will find files in the current directory anyway. (I doubt that this every worked, use \newcommand instead of \DeclareRobustCommand).

Comment: @Ulrike That's what changed!!!  I was replacing \newcommand in various source files and got too enthusiastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This never worked. Don't use a robust command inside `\verbatiminput`. So define your `\getPath` as

```
\newcommand\getPath[1]{\luadirect{getPath(\luastring{#1})}}
```